# Can we install the UFT 11.53 patch on trail version of UFT 11.50?

Tags: hp-uft

I tried to install the UFT 11.53 patch on trail version of the UFT as I have 11 days left for trail to expire. But after installing the patch UFT asking the license and giving the following error.
Can somebody tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you **1)Install Patches** or **2)Repair UFT** or **3)Modify UFT**  finally the setup wizard will prompt to run **UFT license wizard** ,**Debugger**, **DCOM Settings..** 
Here try to cancel license wizard stuff,(If you want u can proceed with DCOM and Debugger)  then restart your system  and Launch UFT(Hope UFT will continue in trail mode).

Download patches here http://www.learnqtp.com/patches/

Please let me know if you need any clarification..